# Waiting time is too high to Get Response from HTTPS site compared with http site

Tags: amazon-web-services, https, wait, httpwebresponse

I am having an MVC website and deployed as both https and http (test version) in amazon aws. I noticed latency with log-in for specific user role in https site compared to http site. When I checked in fiddler/developer tool, I noticed that waiting time is too high (33715 ms) to get html response for https site compared to http site (700 ms). Same log-in module has been used for other role and there is no latency for other roles.

I have checked the code and I did not see any issue with code or database performance and it also working perfectly for http site.

Any idea what could be possible issue for this slowness?

Comment: youll have to provide some more info then that. but 33715ms vs 700ms looks like your code is waiting for some kind of 30 second timeout somewhere.

Answer (score 2):

1. Check the zone of both the servers. Maybe they are on different places.
2. Waiting time is too high means it maybe a code related issue like sometimes a DB query can take more time.

Answer (score 0):

After adding below code, site looks to be working as normal -

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
 });
```